# Left-button click for Silverlight TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox, mouseclick-event

I need TextBox that supports double click, but while trying to code it, i stuck with a problem that Silverlight textbox doesn't raise left-button mouse events if i click inside of text area. So what are possible solutions here? I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom textbox control that inherits from the default `TextBox` and override the `OnMouseLeftButtonUp` method, like this:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

If you need to handle the double click, it would be easier to switch to Silverlight 5 that introduced the concept of a click count. Here is a tutorial for handling the double click: http://www.silverlighthostingnews.com/index.php/archives/440
Basically you will just have to do this:

```
if(e.ClickCount == 2) {...}
```

EDIT: here is how to do in Silverlight 4:

- Create the custom textbox that inherits the default TextBox class and override the mouse events like so:

-

```
public class DoubleClickTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

- Add the [DoubleClickExtender class](http://www.domagoj.pavlesic.com/DoubleClick-in-Silverlight) in your project class.
- In your code-behind, attach to the double click event:

-

```
DoubleClickExtender dce = new DoubleClickExtender(textBox, 300)
dce.DoubleClick += new MyEventHandler(dce_DoubleClick);
```

Comment: Well, switching to newer version is not up to me, but thx for solution, guess i'll use it.

Comment: There are ways to handle double click in SL4 but it is more hacky. Here is how you can do: http://www.domagoj.pavlesic.com/DoubleClick-in-Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to cheat with this one, although I haven't tried this myself

- Change the template of the textbox to have a transparent overlay that
  is IsHitTestVisible = true
- Set the double click event on the overlay.
- If you detect a single
  click on the overlay, do nothing and let it bubble through
- If you detect a double click, set the event handled of the
  mousebuttoneventargs to true and perform your double click action

Please note that double click on Silverlight4 isn't natively supported, so you'll have to come up some way to simulate that.